# getting this error with running ./gradlew genSources command

Tags: java, terminal, minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I'm trying to execute the gradlew genSources command here, but it says I'm using an outdated version of java, and that I at least must have Java version 17.

```
PS D:\Coding Stuff\Java Projekte\Minecraft Mods\fabric-example-mod-1.19> ./gradlew genSources

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Coding Stuff\Java Projekte\Minecraft Mods\fabric-example-mod-1.19\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'fabric-loom', version: '1.0-SNAPSHOT']
> Failed to apply plugin 'fabric-loom'.
   > You are using an outdated version of Java (8). Java 17 or higher is required.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 621ms
```

I went to File > Project Structure > Project and the SDK property is clearly set to openjdk-19, the language level property is set to SDK default(19). I went to Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle, which tells me that the Gradle JVM property is set to Project SDK openjdk-19.

using a Windows 10 machine

Comment: You only _think_ you are using Java 19.  Gradle is finding a Java 8 JVM and using that.  You need to ensure that Gradle has the correct path to an appropriate JVM

Comment: yes, it definetly is a Java 19 JVM. Maybe it's because I've got another jdk version installed on my machine? But I'm using intelliJ and it definetly says that the gradle JVM is set to Project SDK open jdk-19

Comment: Clearly the gradle process has the old JVM 8 earlier in the path.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you must use Java 17, because Minecraft 1.19 uses this Java version :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since minecraft 1.19 was architectured around jdk-17, some methods end up breaking when running it on jdk-19, meaning the game won't even start.
if you set it to run with jdk-17, it should work fine